# Фраза «Ох, уж это...»

Tags: значения

Мать разговаривает с дочерью:

> ... Я скажу отцу, он назначит день, придут его родители, попросят твоей руки...
>   – **Ох, уж эта мне патриархальность**! Да пойми, мне не нужны никакие сваты, родители.

Что значит фраза *Ох, уж это [имя существительное]*? Это что-то в роде *вот какая [имя существительное]*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ох уж это мне [что-то раздражающее]", или, как вариант, "Уж это мне [что-то раздражающее]" (со смысловым ударением на "Уж") - один из устоявшихся оборотов, произошедших из форм междометий в качестве членов предложения, стоящих в связи с другими членами: "Ахти мне горемычной", "Ой ли?", "Увы мне, кудесник, отправляй меня назад". В данном контексте междометия "ох" и "уж" означают раздражение, неприятие, осуждение.

Answer (score 7):

It's something like 'Oh, that [...] has eaten out my brains/has aroused my indignation'.

In short, `Ох, уж эта мне [...]!` means `Damned be [...]!`.

Comment: I'd say it's much less angry than that.

Comment: @Anixx that's not a word one uses lightly. care to explain yourself?

Comment: @Anixx: as you are pretty well aware, using language like that towards other users is a bannable offence.

Answer (score 3):

"Ох" is part of the idiom too, while the "мне" bit is optional. The comma between "ох" and "уж" is unnecessary since it's a set phrase. Someone was hypercorrective about their punctuation.

Its precise meaning is to point to something being repeatedly/notoriously obnoxious or frustrating. It's a little dated — more like something people would say in the 20th century or earlier — but not really obsolete; it's become (or is perhaps in the process of becoming) one of those Russian colloquialisms that are used with self-aware facetiousness, rather than truly spontaneously.

Comment: I don't know if this user was looking for an answer in English, but wouldn't the most logical equivalent be "Oh those...!" ?  In other words, we basically say the same thing in English.

Answer (score -1):

"Dislikes these patriarchal manners"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however we are looking for longer, more informative answers, rather than one-liners.